# Semantic UI popup doesn't work after ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, semantic-ui

i havea popup from Semantic UI, it works. But when I redrawing page using ajax, popups doesn't work anymore. Any idea how to solve? Last time I had a problem witjh click event, i solve :

```
$(document).on('click', '.removeIssue', function (){ ... });
```

Does exist something similar to popup? Thanks

Comment: Without an example or some code, it's hard to precisely advise. It sounds like events bound to the DOM are being lost when you modify/remove those DOM elements (i.e. the popup). So, you can either **(a)** re-initialize the popup after the ajax calls have finished, or **(b)** use jQuery's [Event Delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/), which you've described has worked for you before.

Comment: it like you write- e DOM are being lost when you modify/remove those DOM elements (i.e. the popup